# Is there an efficient way to query if product is installed on Windows and retrieve IdentifyingNumber

Tags: windows, wmic

I'm trying to automate a test process to first uninstall a product if present.

To find the product I've so far found that the information is available through wmi and `wmic product get IdentifyingNumber, name, version | findstr /I /C:"Name"` retrieves the info I need.

This query and search takes a long time, but I couldn't seem to get a wmi where clause to work.

Is there something I can do to make this faster?
Or, Is there some other method to get to the `IdentifyingNumber`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### wmic solution using where

This should be faster as you don't need to pipe the output to `findstr`

```
wmic product where "name like 'Name'" get IdentifyingNumber, name, version
```

Example:

To find the information for iTunes

```
F:\test>wmic product where "name like 'iTunes'" get IdentifyingNumber, name, version
IdentifyingNumber                       Name    Version
{93F2A022-6C37-48B8-B241-FFABD9F60C30}  iTunes  12.1.2.27
```

---

#### Further reading

- [wmic](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html) - Windows Management Instrumentation Command.
- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) is an excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.

Comment: Thank you. That about halves the time it was taking for me, just under a minute down from 2 minutes - about 5 minutes saved per run. I see how the where clause works now too.

Comment: you can also add % in the query to make it more common ,   "name like '%Skype%'"      https://codeslammer.wordpress.com/2009/02/21/wmic-wildcard-search-using-like-and/